# How to make @angular/flex-layout wrap based on screensize

Tags: html, angular, responsive-design

I have 3 divs which i can make bigger or smaller based on the screen-size but cant get it to wrap like bootstrap. So for small screens i want the divs to be stacked vertically, large screen horizontally. eg [image] Anyone know how i do this with Angular2? I chose to use the @angular/flex-layout which i npm'd.

Note: I dont think there is anything in the 'colored box' thats conflicting with anything.

Here is my code...

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  //templateUrl: './app/app.component.html',
  template:`

<div class="flex-container" fxFlex=100>
      <div class="colored box" >
        <div fxFlex.lg=100 fxFlex.md=50>  flexible for screensize  </div>
        <div fxFlex.lg=100> fxFlex </div>
        <div fxFlex=33> fxFlex </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="version">@angular/flex-layout (v2.0.0-beta.0)</div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app/app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent  { 

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use `fxLayout`/`fxLayout.xs` attribute for specifying layout format on different resolution. Where `fxLayout` can accept either `column`/`row` value.

> **column:** division calculation will happen vertically.
>
> **row:** division calculation will happen horizontally.
>
> If you want to target any specific resolution mention it just after
>   fxLayout like `fxLayout.xs="column"`

```
<div class="flex-container" 
     fxLayout="row" 
     fxLayout.xs="column">
  <div class="flex-item" fxFlex=50>  flexible for screensize  </div>
  <div class="flex-item" fxFlex=33> fxFlex </div>
  <div class="flex-item" fxFlex=33> fxFlex </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Pankaj... I am at the start of a steep learning curve, can you explain what this does?

Comment: After your update...ok i think i'm getting that...seems way more complicated than Bootstrap which wraps components based on screensize automatically. Can you give me some code that will achieve my large screen horizontal divs and small screen vertical divs?

Comment: @Fearghal you could check the online example [here](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/responsive), after changing the resolution of window to small div will appear vertically.

Comment: yes, i  went to the site you gave me and could not see the code, the examples are brilliant so it will be very helpful once i see their code

Comment: also, your code works in wrapping the components, However it is not stretching across the screen like my question but instead bunched together in top left hand corner.If you know how to do that, its answered.

Comment: Got it, removed the fxflex.lg=100 and made it fxFlex=33 for each div

Comment: Amend your answer and i can tick as answered :)

Comment: Updated answer, please check

Comment: For anyone that might run onto this and get confused, `fxLayout.xs` means: turn it into a column when you reach the _xs_ size, `xs` as in the extra-small screen size.

Answer (score 37):

Try to use

> fxLayout="row wrap"

, it will move the element into a new line. 
It worked for me, tested on different screen sizes.